# .NET Html viewer/web browser control alternatives

Tags: .net, browser

I m currently using the IE ActiveX (web browser) control in .NET to show HTML inside my application, but it is VERY SLOW (loads of virtual memory eating), and very limited and I would like to swop this out with a fully managed HTML viewer.

This is a different request to [Is there any better web browser control in C# (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703498/is-there-any-better-web-browser-control-in-c-net) as that is about other embedded browsers (Firefox/Gecko). I do not want to embed a browser, I want a  properly managed control.

---

Update (13 Apr 2011): [This post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/managed-html-rendering.html) by Jeff Atwood explains part of the reasoning, for those unclear why this is important/needed.

Comment: You're looking for a browser written *entirely in managed code*? I'm not aware of one. The best you can do is a .NET wrapper for an existing web browser. It's not clear why exactly that's unacceptable to you.

Comment: @Code Gray - a browser control written entirely in managed code, yes. Does it need to be as feature rich as the main stream browsers, not at all. My issue with the embeded browsers so far is just size, the smallest one would double my current system size, they add significant overhead (IE virtual memory usage is 4 times that than the rest of my app) and the wrappers just are poor if you want to do serious work with it.

Comment: I don't mean this to sound rude, but that's a little silly. A browser that was written in entirely managed code would be anything if not *more* bloated than one written in native code. You're definitely going to have *more* overhead with a managed control. My guess is *significantly* more, but not having actually seen one, it's hard to say for certain. I understand that you don't like IE; me neither. But there are other good wrappers available that you should seriously consider. You're not going to find a browser written in .NET.

Comment: @Code Gray - Think you miss the point. First bloat is very broad, I am happy with some bloat in filesize, but I want to avoid things like the virtual memory issue which is MASSIVE across all wrappers. Second having a managed code browser (we not talking a full implementation here either, just a HTML viewer/parser) means that the code could easily be changed. For example if I want to add support for say HTML11 then I could. Considering that this exists in JAVA & Delphi it shows a need and can be done - just not sure what is preventing .NET people from doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After finding Jeff's post I scrolled through the mess of comments and found [HTMLRenderer](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/), which is a codeplex solution. It has CSS 2.1 support plus HTML 4.1 support and is free & OSS (BSD LIcense). The code is a mess unfortunately, but there is only one part which is really worrisome the rest can be cleaned up.

Comment: I wanted to create a [pure css tree](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-tree-menu-framework) but unfortunately this thing doesnt render it the in same way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that good way to go is to use Webkit port for .NET

http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

More info about Webkit itself:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

Comment: As stated in the question "I do not want to embed a browser, I want a properly managed control." This is wrapper to embed webkit.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand Your question.

Comment: You could embed a web browser control and then use one of the great javascript HTML edtors like TinyMCE to edit the HTML

Answer (score -1):

You just arent going to find one.
The complexity of writing a browser, especially in this competative market, is massive.

What you could possibly try, is running a pure Java web browser in .Net, by using [iKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/devguide/net2java.html)

Ideally, one of these browsers, ported to .net would be great, but I cant find any reference to that either.

Two pure Java browsers:

1. [HotJava](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/hotjava/3.0/index.html)
2. [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp)

Comment: I just don't see how embedding a Java browser into a .NET application gets you anywhere. Sure, it's *possible*. But it's not any better than embedding one written in native code, like Webkit, Gecko, etc.