# Correct display of the hyperlink and the label

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

### Description, code and UI

I created a RichTextBox (RTB) in a c#/.net 4.0 Winforms-application.

```
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

        // 
        // richTextBoxProtokoll
        // 
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 332);
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll.Name = "richTextBoxProtokoll";
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(461, 286);
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll.TabIndex = 42;
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll.Text = "";
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll.Visible = false;
        this.richTextBoxProtokoll.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkClickedEventHandler(this.richTextBoxProtokoll_LinkClicked);
```

The RichTextBox `DetectUrls` property has a default value of true, so I have not set this property.

Afterwards I assigned some rtf-data to the control, so that it looks like this (sorry: the text is in german language): -- sorry I can add at most 2 links --

The importend part is the yellow marked part at this picture: [pic01](http://de.tinypic.com/m/i4pbon/1)

I have added a link-tag in the rtf-data. This link-tag consists of a label (which is named: Link) and the real link to something other, which is a file in my case (file:somepath).

Nearely everything is fine. The link works, because a have added a LinkClicked-EventHandler.

### What I would have expected:

What I have expected is like this: [pic02](http://de.tinypic.com/m/i4pbp2/1)

I have defined a label (named: Link) which has to be printed. The link itself has to be silent. It has not to be shown in the RTB.

If I copy the rtf-text of the RTB to a file and open it for example with WordPad, it is shown, how I expect it: -- sorry I can add at most 2 links --

### This is the rtf-code:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Verdana;}}{\colortbl;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green150\blue0;\red0\green0\blue250;\red0\green0\blue250}{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.15.1507;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16\cf0 \par {\b\cf0 Start der Dimitra-IntegrationTests}\par \cf0 27.05.2014 12:31:26\par \cf0 \par \cf0 \par \cf0 -------------------------------\par \cf0 --------- Kategorie: {\b\cf0 Adapter} \cf0 \par \cf0 -------------------------------\par \cf0 \par \cf0 \par \cf0 Es wird folgender Test ausgeführt: {\b\cf0 Test009_Wait_5_sec} \cf0 \par \cf0 \par \cf0      Es wird folgender Teil-Test ausgeführt: {\b\cf0 Teil01}\par \cf0           Es werden die Ergebnisse verglichen: {\b\cf2  --> ok    }\cf0 {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "file:C:\\\\TS_Projekte\\\\DataAdaption\\\\Dimitra\\\\Tests\\\\IntegrationTests\\\\_Results\\\\Erich.Desktop\\\\Adapter\\\\Test009_Wait_5_sec\\\\Teil01\\\\Showdiff_TeilResults.cmd"}}{\fldrslt{\cf0\lang1033 Link}}}\cf0 \par \cf0 \par \cf0 Übersicht über die {\b\cf0 aktuelle } \cf0 Test-Serie:\par \cf0 Gesamtanzahl an Teil-Tests:  1\par \cf0 Anzahl Teil-Tests mit ok:    {\b\cf2 1}\cf0 \par \cf0 Anzahl Teil-Tests mit diffs: {\b\cf2 0}\cf0 \par }
```

### My questions:

- what's wrong with my rtf-code. But only wrong for RTB, not wrong for WordPad?
- how does it work correctly?
- may it be a bug in the MS-RTB? If so: is there a bugfix available?

Additionally:

Somebody told me, that my rtf-code would work correctly in a WPF-Richtext-Control.

Comment: ...If you can't upload the picture, could you link to it or at least describe what it is we're supposed to see?

Comment: I don't have a public accessible dropbox, ..space etc.
Is there a upload-area at stackoverflow.

It is much easier to look at pictures than to desibe it.

I would need at least 10 reputations to be allowed to upload Pictures to stackoverflow

Comment: When I load your RTF code to a RTF-Box and save it to a file it looks like [this](http://de.tinypic.com/r/hvdpvt/8) It this what you expected? Is it right or wrong?

Comment: @TaW

This is exactly the wrong lookout.

What I'm excpeting is like this:would expect is

Comment: @TaW

This is exactly the wrong lookout.

What I'm excpeting is like this:

         Es werden die Ergebnisse verglichen: --> ok  Link

"Link" should be underlined at work like a Link. After clicking my Eventhandler should be called.

The blue formatted text: <file:C:\.....> shoud be invisible.

Comment: I thought so. But that means that the the RTF code you posted doesn't work in WordPad, unless I messed something up..  ((BTW using TinyPic was really easy, no registration, no fuss; it was my first time and I recommend you try it..)

Comment: Thanks TaW for the tip about tinypic.
I uploaded now 4 Pictures.
But at staackoverflow I can add only 2 links to the pictues.

As a beginner at stackoverflow, I'm slightly frusted :-(

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBox is only a wrapper around the Win32 RichEdit control, and so its functionality can be extended by [adding the necessary wrappers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox) to send the messages the RichEdit control needs for setting the link style.

Comment: I have looked to your sourcecode and tried to use it.

The problem is, that we have differnet strategies to use the RTB:
- you put the text directly to the RTB by using richTextBoxEx.SelectedText
- I use a separated class for the rtf-string, build/append this string and assign it to the property richTextBoxEx.Rtf.

This is because I have some other formatted (color, size, fonts, ..) informations in the RTB and hyperlinks, too.

At the moment I don't know how to adopt your methode InsertLink(strrg,string) to my implementation.

Comment: The linked article at least shows why you currently have the problem with links in the RTF control. And the code example there demonstrates the possibility of extending the underlying control, and provides a handy starting-point if you want to extend it in other ways. It's not my code BTW! :) Anyway, if you don't feel like pursuing that approach, try the second answer I'm about to post...

Comment: At the moment I see two chances: 1. I let my application be as it is. The Problem is no paint point. To hide the full path is only nice to have. 2. I use the code for the RTB, you gave me the link. This will be some work for me - for: nice to have.   Changing to html would be too much work for me. 

I'm not sure, how i will decide. May be: point 1.

Comment: `Changing to html would be too much work` - what aspect do you think would be too much work? Hosting the viewer, or assembling the content into HTML instead of RTF? I'm not so sure it would be a lot of work. But then I don't know details of where your RTF string comes from, how it's assembled. But if it was me, I'd knock up a simple app to try it out separately. Anyway, at this point I think you have to maybe try something out, and then make your choice! Hope this input has been helpful.

Comment: 1. My RTF-string is generated by my own application from an own class with methodes like: AppendRedString(..), AppendGreenString, AppendHyperlink. This may be modifyable to generate HTLM-code.

2. My Hyperlink is not a link to another document. It is the pathname of a cmd-batch. From the DetectUrl-Eventhandler I execute a childprocess, with executes the cmd-batch, this compares two files and shows the differences in a second window. The link behaves more like a button, than like a simple document-link.

Fist, I would have to try this separately with a simple app.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to extending the RTF control, do you have the possibility to abandon RTF? Rather than continue to battle with this frankly hideous technology, why not use HTML? You can display HTML in WinForms using a [WebBrowser control](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/displaying-custom-html-in-webbrowser-control) or one of [the alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308762/net-html-viewer-web-browser-control-alternatives).

Comment: Thank you for this tip. When I started with my procets I decided to the richtextbox. I didn't look up for other Technologies.

You are right, I could also use HTML and a WebBrowser.

But, I'm not sure, which one is the better.

RTF is a standard from MS - yes it has some versions. But I had expected, that each software from MS, which supports RTF will work corretly - winform (WinAPI/C, C++, C#, Office, WordPad, etc.), WPF, Silverlight, ..  and have the same Output. My experience is: it isn't.

Comment: to be continued of my comment above:

If I use HTML: it's an open Standard, ok. But will MS-controls work correctly? Will free webbrowsers work correctly?

If I change to html and get problems whats the benefit?

Comment: Create a simple app to try it out. You will have to be the judge of whether it meets your needs, whether it behaves ok in testing. And whether any problems it brings are worse than your present one (doubtful IMHO). Whether using HTML makes it easier to change your app in the future (likely IMHO, as it's easier to read).